# Wordpress. Убрать http:// из URL комментария

Tags: wordpress

Переделал поле URL комментария в город, но не могу справиться с одной проблемой:

```
Город: <?php echo get_comment_author_url( $comment_ID); ?>
```

Происходит вывод

```
Город: http://Москва
```

Как мне убрать http://? 
Спасибо =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) с данным паттерном:

```
Город: <?php echo preg_replace('#^https?://#', '', get_comment_author_url($comment_ID)); ?>
```

Будет работать как для ссылок вида `https://`, так и для `http://`.